# How to unit test a Sails.JS Waterline action without sails lift

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js

I tried to write a unit test for sails without doing a sails lift. I have two simple controllers, `UserController` that has a model with an id, name, & schoolid, then a `SchoolController` with a model that has an id & name using the sails doc: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing. I wrote a simple test with sails lift/sails.lower. I'm able to get the controller waterline action and it works for me, however, if I want to write a simple unit test without lifting sails I get a `User is not defined` error. How can I simply get a sails waterline action without lifting sails? I found one great library wolfpack https://github.com/fdvj/wolfpack but it doesn't work.

```
//SchoolController
function checkSchool(req, res) {
  const id = req.param('id');

  const idquery = ;
  userquery(`SELECT * FROM school WHERE id = ${id}`).then((rows) => {
    const schoolId = rows[0].school;
    User.findOne({ id: schoolId }).exec((school) => {
      res.status(200).send(school);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  checkSchool
};

//SchoolController.test.js

let SchoolController = require('../src/controller/SchoolController');
describe('SchoolController', function(){
    We can test that our controller is calling our Model method with the proper params
    it("should get one school info by user id a given id", function(){
      SchoolController.checkSchool(request, response);
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried running your sails project in console mode with a local redis server?  You'll need to install the local redis server first, then using two terminals: run "redis-server" and "sails console --redis."  More info: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis / https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-console / https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-redis /

Comment: Install the local redis server with : terminal: `npm install sails-redis --save`